# AngularJS Filter on Boolean only works for true

Tags: angularjs

This seems bizarre to me. I am filtering an array of objects like the sample below.

```
{
    "queried": false,

},
{
    "queried": true,
}
```

I am using ng-repeat and a filter.

```
ng-repeat="message in messages |  filter:{queried:true} ">
```

When I set the filter to queried:true I get the objects which have queried:true.

However if I set the filter to queried:false I get **all** the objects.

Same results for queried:!true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put a jsfiddle together and it seems to work for me. Make sure you are using the right angular version.

```
function HelloCntl($scope) {
    $scope.messages = [{'queried':true}, {'queried':true},{'queried':false}, {'queried':false},{'queried':true}];
```

Here is the View

```
<div ng:app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="HelloCntl">

     <p> True results:</p>
   <div ng:repeat="message in messages | filter:{queried:true} ">
       {{message.queried}}         
    </div>
     <br/>
      <p> True results:</p>
   <div ng:repeat="message in messages | filter:{queried:false} ">
       {{message.queried}}         
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

[Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CBgcP/620/)

Comment: Make sure you are using the right angular version. This fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure please see that demo

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);



app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.messages = [{
    "queried": false,

  }, {
    "queried": true,
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="enable" ng-value="false">False
  <input type="radio" ng-model="enable" ng-value="true">True
  <br/>
  <hr/>

  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="message in messages |  filter:{queried:enable} ">{{message}}</li>
  </div>
</body>
```